# Join two tables and get data only if it matches data from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

```
 Tbl1 
 AuthID         ClientID          ClientNote
 1              12                First Appointment
 2              13                First Appointment


 tbl2
 EligID         ClientID          TypeA          DateA
 1              12                1              12/30/2015
 2              12                2              5/30/2016
 3              13                1              2/13/2016
 4              13                2              7/30/2016
```

I want to only to select clients from `tbl1` which have `TypeA = 1` and `DateA is between 01/01/2016 and 06/30/2016` in `tbl2`.

Comment: What have you tried? This is a pretty straight forward inner join with a where clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT tbl1.*
  FROM tbl1
  INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.ClientID = tbl2.ClientID
WHERE tbl2.TypeA = 1 AND tbl2.DateA BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-06-30'
```

Should get done what you are looking for.